# Unable to format laptop SSD because it's behaving as if it was read-only

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, formatting, diskpart

I recently ran into some very strange behavior when trying to recover files and reinstall Windows 10 on a laptop. Essentially, I have an SSD in an MSI laptop with multiple partitions. I have recovered the files I wanted to recover and backed them up to an external HDD, but now I need to reinstall Windows in order to make it bootable again. The problem is that there is insufficient free space on any partition to install Windows 10, which led me to try formatting the drive.

I started `diskpart` from a command prompt through a Windows recovery USB. I tried multiple ways of formatting the drive (`clean`, deleting and recreating the partitions, formatting the volumes), with every approach `diskpart` says it was successful, but a simple `list vol` still shows me that all the volumes from the disk I just formatted still exist, with all the data on them.

I also tried manually deleting files through the command prompt (using `del`). This also appeared to initially be successful, and a `dir` right afterwards showed all the files to be deleted. However, after restarting the machine, all the files were back.

It would appear that the SSD is somehow write-protected (reading works fine, verified by copying files to external HDD and opening them on another PC). `diskpart` does not, however, show the SSD or any partition I tried to format as `readonly`. Therefore I tried eliminating some possible culprits in the Windows Registry, using these two commands:

`REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Exploit Guard\Controlled Folder Access" /v EnableControlledFolderAccess /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

`REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

Unfortunately the problem still persists. Deleting or formatting the partitions using the GUI from the Windows installation USB also doesn't work, it just acts like a no-op and nothing changes about the partitions.

This leaves me with a disk which seems to be impervious to any kind of formatting or file deletion, but those operations always succeed (no error). I am completely at wit's end, the only possible explanation that comes to mind would be that the disk has some kind of hardware write protection and that the delete "succeeded" by being written in cache only, but then the write through to the actual disk from the cache failed at a later time. I don't see how this would be possible however, since this is an SSD which is built into the laptop in question. Testing the disk with another machine is out of the question, since that would mean completely disassembling the laptop.

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome.

Comment: I once had a USB pen drive with the same problem, deleting/formatting always succeed, but all the stuff will magically reappear if I press F5...it was caused by a virus; Maybe your problem is also caused by a virus, find a way to connect your laptop's ssd to a clean computer while your laptop is off if possible, then run the scans.

Answer (score 1):

What about booting the Laptop from a Windows 10 installation USB? Does it let you delete partitions and create new ones during the installation? Anytime I had problems with partitions, a clean Windows installation would fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this more clear in my question but no, in the Windows installation dialog I'm unable to manipulate the partitions. If I click format or delete, it doesn't do anything to the partition (no error, nothing happens). This is why I'm unable to do a clean Windows install, which is what I ultimately want to do.

Comment: Are you able to use CrystalDiskInfo and look at the lifetime write total and status?  Is it possible that the drive has had so much written to it, that it's at the end of its life?

Comment: And I'll add another suggestion -  what about booting from a Linux USB? Does it behave differently?

Comment: The Windows on this machine is unbootable unfortunately, so no. I tried to fix the boot but I came to the conclusion that a clean install is the best option, since I managed to recover the important files anyway. The laptop is 1 year old, so I highly doubt that the SSD is already dead.

Comment: The Linux USB is actually a pretty good idea, I have a Linux Mint USB somewhere, so I'll try to format the disk using that when I get the chance. Thanks for the suggestion!